# Passing a variable in Snowflake Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am running a query inside the procedure(using Javascript) and passing a variable to where condition , getting error.
please correct me here.

`var v='col1' select * from table1 t where t.v='string'`

in above query i am using variable in where condition instead of column name.
how do we pass a variable here(`t.v`)

Thanks

Comment: So with t.v. you mean your variable v?

Comment: yes it is variable

Comment: Can you share more code from the procedure? That line doesn't seem like valid code to me

Comment: due to security reasons i am not able to share the code but code looks like below.

Comment: due to security reasons i am not able to share the code but code looks like below.

`var v='col1' 
var sql_stmt=snowflake.execute({sqlText: "select * from table1 t1 where t1.${v}='string' ; "`

here when i am passing variable in where condition i.e t1.v, it is not taking , throwing below error 

`compilation error , error code: 100183 
unexpected t1.v`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backquote (`) to be able to use template strings:

```
create table table1 ( col1 varchar, col2 varchar);
insert into table1 values ('string','Gokhan'), ('int','1');

create or replace procedure test_sp( v varchar)
returns string  
language javascript
as
$$
var v=V; // get the param
var result=snowflake.execute({sqlText: `select * from table1 t1 where t1.${v}='string'; ` } );
result.next();
return result.getColumnValue(2);
$$;

call test_sp('col1');

+---------+
| TEST_SP |
+---------+
| Gokhan  |
+---------+
```

Based on the comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEMP(IN_V VARCHAR) RETURNS VARCHAR(100) LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS  
$$ var v_brand ='brand'; 
var v1='col1' ;
var ALERT_CURSOR=snowflake.execute({sqlText: "SELECT col1,col2 FROM CDW_US_DIMS_DB.FCT_ALERTS_PARAMS_OBR WHERE col1='"+IN_V+"' "});  
while(ALERT_CURSOR.next()) { var col1=ALERT_CURSOR.getColumnValue(1); var col2=ALERT_CURSOR.getColumnValue(2);
   if (v_brand == 'v_'+col4.trim()) { v_brand=col2; } else {v_brand=col3;}
v_WORK_SQL_ALRT_VOL1 = snowflake.execute({sqlText: "create temporary table CDW_DB.TEMP1(col1 INTEGER,col2 VARCHAR(255),RNK INTEGER);"}) 
v_WORK_SQL_ALRT_VOL2 = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `insert into CDW_DB.TEMP1 select DISTINCT  FCT.COL1,FCT.COL2 , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FCT.COL1 ORDER BY FCT.COL2 ASC) AS RNK from CDW_DB.FCT_TBL FCT WHERE COL1 <> -1 and FCT.${v_brand} QUALIFY  RNK=1;`}); 
var v_DROP_VOL_TBL1 =snowflake.execute({sqltext:"DROP TABLE CDW_DB.TEMP1"}); } return v_brand; 
$$;
```

Comment: not working, throwing error
`syntax error  Unexpected $.`

Comment: Must have been a copy/paste error. Works great for me.

Comment: given script is working fine, but in my script when i am passing the variable its giving error

Comment: BalajiAWS, I tried to provide the best answer although you didn't provide required information. Unfortunately I can't help further unless you share simplified version of your script and how you pass the variable.

Comment: not able to post the procedure DDL as it is crossing character limit that is allowed by stackoverflow, i will post 2 comments for the same.

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEMP(IN_V VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS 
$$
var v_brand ='brand';
var v1='col1'
var ALERT_CURSOR=snowflake.execute({sqlText: "SELECT col1,col2 FROM CDW_US_DIMS_DB.FCT_ALERTS_PARAMS_OBR WHERE col1='"+IN_V+"' "});

while(ALERT_CURSOR.next())
{
var col1=ALERT_CURSOR.getColumnValue(1);
var col2=ALERT_CURSOR.getColumnValue(2);
    if (v_brand == 'v_'+col4.trim()) 
    {   
    v_brand=col2;
    }
 else {v_brand=col3;}`

Comment: `v_WORK_SQL_ALRT_VOL1 = snowflake.execute({sqlText: ``create temporary table CDW_DB.TEMP1(col1 INTEGER,col2 VARCHAR(255),RNK INTEGER);``})
v_WORK_SQL_ALRT_VOL2 = snowflake.execute({sqlText:``insert into CDW_DB.TEMP1 select DISTINCT  FCT.COL1,FCT.COL2 , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FCT.COL1 ORDER BY FCT.COL2 ASC) AS RNK from CDW_DB.FCT_TBL FCT WHERE COL1 <> -1 and FCT.${v_brand} QUALIFY  RNK=1;``});
var v_DROP_VOL_TBL1 =snowflake.execute({sqltext:"DROP TABLE CDW_DB.TEMP1"});
}
return v_brand;
$$
;`

Comment: call statement CALL SP_TEMP('brand');
throwing following error `empty argument passed`

Comment: Dear Balaji, I highly recommend you to share the function source in a formatted way in the initial question instead of in comments. Second thing, if you share the FULL error message, we can help you quicker. Anyway the issue is about DOUBLE backquates you used. I will update my answer with correct - as I don't have tables, I just know that it will not give the error you complaint but not sure if it will work.

Comment: i have used double back quotes for the comments, but in my script i have used only one back quote

Comment: Okay but when I called "call SP_TEMP('br and');", I do not get any error for my corrected version. Have you checked the corrected version?

Comment: may i know  what modification you did, i couldnt see any changes.